# Can't link with the cross-built Arm aarch64 TensorFlow? Undefined reference to GLIBC

Tags: c, tensorflow, gcc, glibc, tensorflow-lite

I cross-built the TensorFlow Lite C API shared library `libtensorflowlite_c.so`: my host machine was Linux Ubuntu `x86 64`, and I built the library for Arm `aarch64` using this [toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu/11.2-2022.02/binrel/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz). I built it using existing CMake build files:

```
cmake \
  -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux \
  -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=${PROCESSOR} \
  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${ARMCC_PREFIX}gcc \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${ARMCC_PREFIX}g++ \
  -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="${ARMCC_FLAGS}" \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="${ARMCC_FLAGS}" \
  -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=OFF \
  ./tensorflow/lite/c/

cmake --build . --parallel 4 --clean-first
```

Then I went to the Arm `aarch64` Ubuntu machine (20.02), and tried to link the library with a test program.

But I got a bunch of "undefined references" to [GLIBC](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/):

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/git/myproj/subprojects/tensorflow/mycom/binaries/aarch64/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `fstat@GLIBC_2.33'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/git/myproj/subprojects/tensorflow/mycom/binaries/aarch64/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `__libc_single_threaded@GLIBC_2.32'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/git/myproj/subprojects/tensorflow/mycom/binaries/aarch64/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `pthread_join@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/git/myproj/subprojects/tensorflow/mycom/binaries/aarch64/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `dlsym@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/git/myproj/subprojects/tensorflow/mycom/binaries/aarch64/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()@GLIBCXX_3.4.29'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/git/myproj/subprojects/tensorflow/mycom/binaries/aarch64/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `stat@GLIBC_2.33'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/git/myproj/subprojects/tensorflow/mycom/binaries/aarch64/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `dlopen@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/git/myproj/subprojects/tensorflow/mycom/binaries/aarch64/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `pthread_once@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/git/myproj/subprojects/tensorflow/mycom/binaries/aarch64/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `pthread_create@GLIBC_2.34'
```

Here is the part of the linker command line:

`--start-group libmyproj.a mysublib.a myfe.a liblapacke.a liblapack.a librefblas.a myml.a -lm -lgfortran libtensorflowlite_c.so -Wl,--end-group`

When I built the lib natively on `x86 64` it linked and ran just fine. What's the problem with the Arm cross-build?

The `ldd --version` gives me the same output for both x86_64 host machine and target Arm machine: `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.7) 2.31`.

So it's v2.31!

I wander where do those dependencies to GLIBC_2.33, GLIBC_2.34, and GLIBC_2.32 come from?

Comment: How did you cross-build the library?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I used existing TensorFlow CMake build files. Added info to the question.

Comment: You should use the same (or older) ARM-glibc, libpthread, libstdc++, etc version in your x86_64/Ubuntu system as you use in the target system. (These version numbers are meant to solve some compatibility problems. Unfortunately, they do create other compatibility problems, but that's how Computer Science works.)

Comment: `ldd --version` gives me the same output for both x86_64 host machine and target Arm machine: `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.7) 2.31`. I wander where do those dependencies to GLIBC_2.33, GLIBC_2.34, and GLIBC_2.32 come from??

Comment: Could it be that my [cross-build toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu/11.2-2022.02/binrel/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz) uses its own glibc?

Comment: Indeed, the toolchain contains `aarch64-none-linux-gnu/libc/lib64/libc.so.6`, which is the GLIBC shared library. I need to find out the version somehow.

Comment: OK, I just copied the `libc.so.6` from the toolchain to the Arm machine `/temp/` and executed it. It says: `GNU C Library (GNU) stable release version 2.34.`. Seems like the toolchain is too fresh, contains newer glibc than the target system.